# align-items-center not working bootstrap 5

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to vertically center a `div` or `img` element within another div element. However when I put `align-items-center">`, nothing happens. I've tried changing the display properties of both elements, and nothing seems to work.

```
<div class="d-flex border p-3">
    <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$other->logo) }}" alt="{{ $other->title }}"
         class="flex-shrink-0 me-3 mt-3 rounded-circle" style="width:60px;height:60px;">
    <div class="align-items-center">
        <h6><a class="text-decoration-none text-primary" href="{{ $other->path() }}">{{ $other->title }}</a></h6>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's working, try this one and resolve issue!

```css
.flex-direction-column{flex-direction:column;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center border p-3">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTtRAI0DozVRaWKStSuxNvFECLt484KOYdjgA&usqp=CAU" alt="title"
         class="flex-shrink-0 rounded-circle" style="width:60px;height:60px;">
    <div class="">
        <h6><a class="text-decoration-none text-primary" href="#">othertitle </a></h6>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center flex-direction-column justify-content-center   border p-3">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTtRAI0DozVRaWKStSuxNvFECLt484KOYdjgA&usqp=CAU" alt="title"
         class="flex-shrink-0 mb-3 rounded-circle" style="width:60px;height:60px;">
    <div class="">
        <h6><a class="text-decoration-none text-primary" href="#">othertitle </a></h6>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center border p-3">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTtRAI0DozVRaWKStSuxNvFECLt484KOYdjgA&usqp=CAU" alt="title"
         class="flex-shrink-0 rounded-circle" style="width:60px;height:60px;">
    <div class="">
        <h6><a class="text-decoration-none  text-primary" href="#">othertitle </a></h6>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

the align-items-center is not used by the children, you should  give it to the box which has the flex property ,at your code ,it's `<div class="d-flex border p-3">`, you can try it